# plutil directory Value (null) not valid for key path

Tags: macos, command-line, plist

I'm trying to create a plist but getting the error:  Value (null) not valid for key path Architectures.com.apple

/usr/bin/plutil -insert "Architectures" -dictionary /Users/test/com.apple.Architectures.plist

/usr/bin/plutil -insert "Architectures"."com.apple" -dictionary /Users/test/com.apple.Architectures.plist

if I replace "com.apple" to something with out the . (dot) it works fine

how do I escape the dot character inside double quotes for the instep argument of plutil?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a backslash to escape the `.`: `\.`.

```
/usr/bin/plutil -insert "Architectures"."com\.apple" -dictionary /Users/test/com.apple.Architectures.plist
```